# Problem Using Geocode and Place Parameters with Twitter Search API V2

Tags: twitter, postman, twitter-api-v2

I have a Twitter Basic plan so I can use Twitter API V2.
The problem is that I got the below error when I added geocode, place, place_country, has:geo. Maybe the basic plan doesn't provide geo-based search but I couldn't see anything about it on documentation.
Can you help me with this issue? Am I sending it wrong or does the BASIC plan not allow me to search based on geo?

The place_country, point_radius, place parameters were tried on Postman. I create query without these parameters then I don't get any error.

here is the URLs which created by me:
1- https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=place%3A%22istanbul%22%20%28sel%29
2- https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=point_radius%3A%5B29.041998%2041.079153%2010km%5D%20%28sel%29
3- https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=place_country%3ATR%20%28sel%29

here is the errors(I get always same error just the key word is changing according to which URL I sent):

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "parameters": {
                "query": [
                    "place_country:TR (sel)"
                ]
            },
            "message": "There were errors processing your request: Reference to invalid operator 'place_country'. Operator is not available in current product or product packaging. Please refer to complete available operator list at . (at position 1)"
        }


    ],
    "title": "Invalid Request",
    "detail": "One or more parameters to your request was invalid.",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"
}
```